# How do I let width of table determine width of entire page

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that contains a table. The table is dynamically generated from a database on the server side. I would like the width of the table to determine the width of the entire page. That is, other block elements above and below the table should take on the same width as the table.

I do not want to use fixed widths. I prefer a pure css solution but if fudging things with JavaScript is the only way, then so be it. I need fairly wide browser support.

I tried using a `div` with `display: inline-block` around the table and the other block elements. The idea was to have the `div` "shrink to fit" around the table and thereby set the width of the other elements. This did not work and I think it's because the `div` does not know which of the elements inside should be the "master", determining the width for the other elements.

**Edit**: Added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z3ru/. In this example, I would like the paragraph above the table to be the same width as the table (not the other way around). I do not want to use a fixed width for the table or paragraph.

**Edit 2**: Conceptually, what I am looking for can be imagined as if the table is rendered alone in a separate document. Then, the rendered table is inserted into a new document and the width of the rendered table is used for setting the width of the new document. So, nothing in the final document affected the rendering of the table, and the table width becomes the only factor in deciding the width of the final document.

Comment: AFAIK, tables will naturally shrink or grow according to their content. Setting `width:100%` will only force it to fill the available document space, not force the document to adapt to the table. If you don't want your `<th>`'s wrapping, you could apply `nowrap` to their content, but that's about all you can do other than give the table an absolute (or min) width.

Comment: What about a Fiddle? With your rep points I believe you should know the basic requirements of a question...

Comment: @Terry: I don't usually hang out over here in HTML/CSS-land. Do you have a pointer to the requirements?

Comment: @Terry: You linked to a bogus site for JSFiddle. Could you edit your comment?

Comment: @RogerDahl [Edited] It's not a strict requirement per se, but when you need help with HTML and CSS (where layouts are involved), it's always good to give an example with minimal code that replicates/illustrates the problem you are presenting - words sometimes don't suffice. I'd recommend [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a previous answer here is correct already: treboothjd6.

## Conclusion:

lt is not possible.

## workarounds

### Setting width

Regarding tables this is very unfortunate and in my opinion, this lack of css solution is a leading cause of css mess, because most css developers will set a width for either the entire table or its columns. This can cause inconsistencies with spacing and requires rigid strictness going forward with all further dimensions. Then use that same width for the other desired elements for better design constraints.

### Getting computed table width with javascript

There is another solution which is less used, is a viable solution, but it does require javascript.

1. Use javascript to place a className: eg: .jsEnabled or use equivalent - modernizr.
2. In your css, hide the parent class, to prevent flashing, flickering, glitches of delayed browser rendering between previous width and desired width.
3. In Javascript detect the computed width of the table. The table visibility is hidden, not none, so the browser still can detect its taken up width. Then use that width to dynamically set the desired other elements, ie the parent.
4. Now use javascript to reshow the parent element.

Since most websites depend on js now anyway this solution provides the dynamic nature you are looking for with less css messiness going forward without having to adhere to a cascade of dimensions predetermined by a chosen width as in previous workaround.

Example codepen:
https://codepen.io/inspiraller/pen/bGEeNeQ?editors=1111

#### js

```js
const tablewidth = (strParentSelector, strTableSelector) => {
  const getWidth = $elem => {
    const computed = window.getComputedStyle($elem);
    return computed.getPropertyValue('width');
  };
  const setWidth = ($elem, width) => {
    $elem.style.width = width;
  };
  const show = $elem => {
    $elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
 
  const $parent = document.querySelector(strParentSelector);
  const $table = document.querySelector(strTableSelector);
  const width = getWidth($table);

  setWidth($parent, width);
  show($parent);
};

const enableJS = () => {
  document.body.classList.add("jsEnabled");
}

const docReady = fn => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
        setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
}  

enableJS();
docReady(() => {
  tablewidth('.someParent', '.tableGeneric');
});
```

#### css

```css
.jsEnabled .someParent {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

#### html

```html
<section class="someParent">
<table class="tableGeneric" summary="Test Diary">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="thtd thtd--date">
        DATE
      </th>
      <th class="thtd thtd--time">
        TIME
      </th>
      <th class="thtd thtd--cat_dudar_its_friend">
        CAT
      </th>
      <th class="thtd thtd--subcat">
        SUBCAT
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0100 ">0100</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--sup ">sup</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--zinc,_mag,_niacn_200mg ">zinc, mag, niacn 200mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0200 ">0200</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--feel ">feel</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--tired ">tired</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0300 ">0300</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--sup ">sup</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--zinc,_mag,_niacn_200mg ">zinc, mag, niacn 200mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0400 ">0400</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--sup ">sup</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--zinc,_mag,_niacn_200mg ">zinc, mag, niacn 200mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0500 ">0500</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--feel ">feel</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--tired ">tired</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0630 ">0630</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--sup ">sup</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--zinc,_mag,_niacn_200mg ">zinc, mag, niacn 200mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0700 ">0700</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--sup ">sup</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--zinc,_mag,_niacn_200mg ">zinc, mag, niacn 200mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thtd thtd--2018 ">2018</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--0800 ">0800</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--feel ">feel</td>
      <td class="thtd thtd--tired ">tired</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <p>This text should nicely be the same width as the table. If it doesn't happen to be the same width as the table then this is not what I want. I reiterate, as its very important that this paragraph text does indeed wrap at the same width as the table.
</section>
```

## React using Typescript and forwardRef example

- https://codepen.io/inspiraller/pen/abdZvzM?editors=1111

Comment: I've updated a react version in typescript for this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/tablewidthtypescriptrefs-is9qx?codemirror=1

Answer (score 2):

- Lets call the initially rendered width of the `wrap` as X.
- `wrap`, when initially rendered and without any width specified, will automatically fill all available horizontal space on the screen available to it. In this case, the entire width of the document. Therefore, in this case, X = 100% of the document.
- You *cannot* make X less than 100% without specifying a new width (aside from methods that are of no use here).
- Using CSS, you can make the `table` the only deciding factor to the expansion of `wrap`, as it will naturally expand to include a table that grows beyond X.
- To make the `wrap` shrink below X, to a dynamic value (the natural width of the `table`) you will have to use Javascript. This will mean that the document will load, *then* the table width is ascertained (`var w = $( "table" ).width()`), *then* that width is applied to `wrap` (`$("#wrap").css("width":w)`).

Answer (score 2):

With a wrap div around both the table and the text, you would need to have reverse inheritance and have the wrap div inherit the width of the table. Unfortunately, though many of us want it, there is no reverse inheritance. Alternatively, you would just go straight to having the `<p>` element inherit the width of the table naturally, which is also impossible from what I know. The only way to inherit width is from the parent, so in this situation the parent of the `<p>` would have to be the table, which wouldn't work even if the table wasn't generated dynamically because putting the `<p>` element in table would affect its width and you'd end up telling the `<p>` element to inherit its own width. Reverse inheritance and a parent selector are in high demand but don't exist. I think the only way you can do this is with JavaScript.

I know of no way to do it only in HTML and CSS, so cheers to anyone who figures it out. I am intrigued by this question and I wonder if there is something I'm missing.

I believe JavaScript is the way to go.

Comment: This makes sense to me. You and @Eamonn seems to have come to the same conclusion. I will leave the question open just in case someone comes along with a CSS-only solution now or in the future. I hope you don't mind. Thank you for your work on this.

Answer (score 0):

What about set tablels with relative?

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spSSC/1/) with a fixed body width and a table inside with 100% width.

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not want to use fixed widths. Thank you.

Comment: But 100% is not fixed it is inheritet from it's  parent element and depends on thats dimensions

Comment: You have set a fixed width of 200px on the body though.

Comment: Yes just to show the inhertit effect... here without... http://jsfiddle.net/spSSC/2/ .. and you'll see the table has a with of the entire page.

Comment: Here a fiddle of yours wich implement the with with relative width http://jsfiddle.net/5Z3ru/1/

Comment: Thank you, @Bernhard, but I still fail to see how this answers the question. See the edit with example and clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
table {
 width:19.85em;
}

#wrap p {
    width:19.85em;
}
```

EMs are similar to PX but they are scalable. For that reason I use them for pretty much everything. I found the width of the table in EMs (and made it that just in case) and set that as the width of the wrap. You could remove the wrap and give the `<p>` a class with this width if you want. And you don't really need the width of the table to be 19.85em, but it's a good reminder of what the width of the `<p>` or wrap should be. Anyway, in any situation like this, try using EMs instead of PX because they're scalable.

Comment: The contents of the table are dynamic (rendered from a database), so this approach does not work.